# Problema al subir una imagen a Strapi mediante un POST en React Native

Tags: nodejs, imagen, react-native, post, strapi

Tengo un problema que no puedo solucionar hace mucho.
Tengo una API creada con Strapi v3 ya en un servidor VPS funcionando y estoy desarrollando una app en React native con el unico fin de cargar/crear nuevos productos a mi e-commerce.
Cada producto es on objeto con title, price, description e imagenes, entre otras cosas. Ya logré crear productos con mi app móvil (ya me aparecen en Strapi -> products) pero al intentar mandarle imágenes me sale error 500 "Internal Server Error".

Mi llamada a la API

```
export async function addNewProductApi(product) {
  try {
    const url = `${API_URL}/products`;
    const params = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ product }),
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, params);
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Mi funcion en el botón Agregar producto

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues(),
    validationSchema: Yup.object(validationSchema()),
    onSubmit: async (formData) => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await addNewProductApi(formData);
        navigation.goBack();
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    },
  });
```

Mi formData

```
combustible: "NAFTA"
description: "Mdldldldl"
id: ""
images: Array(1)
0: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/62DEF53A-24A4-4C7D-A862-BCE75F252918/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540leoolmos08%252Fsessarego-app/ImagePicker/46B09F66-262A-4980-A7A9-A76535D0A1DC.png"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
kilometros: "Nfkdkfk"
marca: "FORD"
modelo: "Ndksks"
price: "Msmssm"
title: "Ksksk"
transmision: "AUTOMATICO"
trucktype: "Ndkdkdkdl"
vehicleType: "PICK-UP"
year: "Mdmdlf
```

Esto tengo en api/product/controllers/product.js

```
module.exports = {
                async create(ctx) {
                const { product } = ctx.request.body;
                const createProduct = [];
                const data = {
                        title: product.title,
                        images: product.images,
                        marca: product.marca,
                        modelo: product.modelo,
                        kilometros: product.kilometros,
                        year: product.year,
                        combustible: product.combustible,
                        description: product.description,
                        transmision: product.transmision,
                        trucktype: product.trucktype,
                        vehicleType: product.vehicleType,
                        price: product.price,
                };
                const validData = await strapi.entityValidator.validateEntityCreation(
            strapi.models.product,
            data
          );
                const entry = await strapi.query("product").create(validData);
                createProduct.push(entry);
                return createProduct;
        },

};
```

Desde ya agradezco la ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error reside en el código que usas para hacer la llamada a la **API**, así que para enviar una imagen correctamente hacia algún servicio de `Strapi` podrías hacerlo de diferentes maneras.

Puedes intentar enviar una petición **POST** primero con la ruta de la imagen y luego usas la `id` o `url` para enviarlo como el parámetro `body`.

```js
export async function addNewProductApi(product) {
  try {
    const url = `${API_URL}/products`;
    const params = {
      method: "POST",
      body: product.images,
    };
    const response = await fetch(url, params).then((response) => {
        const fileId = response.data[0].id;
        product.images=fileId;
        const params = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ product });
        }
        return await response.json();
    )
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

(opcional) Método `blob` usando la ruta del archivo.

```js
export async function addNewProductApi(product) {
    for (let i=0; i<product.images.length; i++) {
        let imgBlob = await (await fetch(product.images[i])).blob();
        product.images[i] = imgBlob;
    }
    //...
    const params = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ product }), // Puedes intentar sin usar JSON.stringify
    };
    //...
}
```

entonces al momento de recibir la respuesta usas `URL.createObjectURL(response.image)` o usar un ciclo de iteraciones para poder usar el método de `URL` sobre los valores del arreglo.